# Setting Port for rs485 comunication linux

Tags: c, linux, configuration, serial-port, rs485

I have a problem with set up a good parameters for my rs485 transmission. Already i am working on this 4th day and i have no idea why it doesn't work.

I am writting a program, which will be communication with other device via rs485. I have a minicomputer with i.MX6 and Linux Linaro. When I try to send special frame running my program on my minicomp it send but, my device doesn't responsible. Furthermore when i send echo from my PC with the same correct frame like in my program device responds. So problem is correct configuration my UART port /dev/ttyUSB.

I need baud rate 115200 and frame 8 bit and 1 stop bit.

```
void SetUARTPort()
{

    int errnum;
    ctrl485.flags |= SER_RS485_ENABLED;
    ctrl485.flags |= SER_RS485_RX_DURING_TX;
    ctrl485.delay_rts_before_send = 0;
    ctrl485.delay_rts_after_send = 0;


    status = ioctl(fd, TIOCSRS485, &ctrl485);
    if (status <0 )
    {
             printf("%s: Unable to configure port in 485 mode, status (%i)\n", dev, status);
             errnum = errno;
                  fprintf(stderr, "Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
                  fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errnum ));
     }

    option.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CSTOPB | CLOCAL ;
    option.c_iflag = 0;
    option.c_oflag = 0;
    option.c_lflag = 0;
    option.c_iflag = IGNPAR | IGNBRK;

    speed = B115200 ;
    tcgetattr(fd, &option);
    cfsetospeed(&option, speed); //TX baude rate
    cfsetispeed(&option, speed); // RX baude rate
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &option); //set new serial config}
```

The last things is that ioctl problem. When i start program i had aN error like:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0: Unable to configure port in 485 mode, status (-1)
Value of errno:25. Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I think i try a lot of thing but i still don't have no idea why it doesn't work. 
Anybody can help me?

cvanny.

Comment: There may be hardware and or wiring issues as well as configuration (full duplex vs half duplex mode) you'll have to deal with as well as coding... Here's a link from kernel.org that gives some sample USER code that may help:  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt  I notice you are using a USB, does that mean you are using a USB to RS485 converter?  If so, its specs may indicate the baud rate it will support as well as half/full duplex configuration

Comment: Only a handful of serial port drivers actually support the Linux RS485 extensions.  The ioctl() error you're seeing clearly indicates that the driver you're using is not one of them.  Also your termios setup is not POSIX-compliant and out-of-sequence with respect to the **tcgetattr()** call; see [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).  *" I have a minicomputer"* -- FYI minicomputers were deprecated back in the 1990s when microprocessors replaced them.  Don't make up you own jargon

Comment: Ok, problem with ioctl() i resolved. I correct the tcgetattr() with the POSIX standard and i still doesnt respond from my device. I set up 115k2 baud, 8 bits , 1start bit, 1 stop bit, parity even and half-duplex. At the moment I dont have any idea where is the problem and what I doing wrong.